# Microsoft system executable copy discrepency

Tags: c++, windows

I have been exploring the ins and outs of Windows system files, and noticed a 
curious thing:  if I perform a low level bitwise copy of a Windows system 
executable to a target location of my choosing the resulting file is smaller than
the original.

Example:  I wrote a small program to copy the ubiquitous calc.exe executable file...

```
C:\test> copyit c:\windows\system32\calc.exe c:\test\calc.exe
```

This is the resulting file:

```
C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is DEAD-BEEF

 Directory of C:\test

02/08/2014  03:37 PM    <DIR>          .
02/08/2014  03:37 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/08/2014  03:37 PM           798,720 calc.exe
               1 File(s)        798,720 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  291,059,347,456 bytes free
```

This is interesting because looking at C:\windows\system32\calc.exe gives me...

```
C:\test>dir c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is DEAD-BEEF

 Directory of c:\Windows\System32

08/22/2013  05:51 AM           922,112 calc.exe     <------Why is this larger?
               1 File(s)        922,112 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  291,059,322,880 bytes free
```

For your viewing pleasure, the "copyit" program I wrote in C++:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    std::ifstream is( argv[0], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );
    std::ofstream os( argv[1], std::ios::out| std::ios::binary );

    is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos size = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0);

    char* buffer = new char[(size_t)size];

    is.read(buffer, size);
    os.write(buffer, size);

    delete [] buffer;

    os.close();
    is.close();

    return 0;
}
```

If I set a break point in the app and examine the size variable after the tellg() call I
see 798720.

???

Note that the resulting calc.exe will not run in my test directory, but if I lower my
UAC security settings it will run.

What could account for this size difference?  Some soft of meta data bundled with the 
system32\calc.exe?  If so, why wouldn't my little copy program just copy that was well 
since it is in the same file?  Is Microsoft bundling some certs for, say, TrustedInstaller
to use?  If so, again, WHY IS THAT NOT COPIED by my little application?

If I look at the two files using peexplorer... they appear *exactly* the same.  Same with
using a hexeditor.

Using Cywin's md5sum, the files result in different hashes.

Running my app on other non-MS system executables results in a perfect copy, both size and
hash and the execuatbles run without touching UAC controls.

I rewrote copyit using the CopyFile API... same result.  Also with _fopen().  Ditto.
I highly suspect I have run across some undocumented security features.

Comment: If you're opening the file as `binary`, why would you allocate a `wchar_t* buffer`? You're trying to copy **binary bytes**, not **wide characters**. No wonder the files don't match (or hash the same).

Comment: Note that files can contain Alternate Data Streams, but you would not see it when you check the file size. The file size just applies to the normal data stream. see [Alternate Data Streams in NTFS](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx)

Comment: Excellent point @Ken White, however note that changing the buffer to be char* instead of wchar_t* only has the effect that I am not allocating the buffer to be twice as big as it needs to be.  Since all IO is in binary mode the wchar_t has no effect (aside from being twice as large as it needs to be).  The resultant checksums between the two versions are identical. I will update the shown code to reflect your bug catch however, as it can distract from the question at hand.

Comment: @Wimmel I have checked for calc.exe containing ADS using the Sysinternals too "Streams".... none found.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably running a 64 bit version of windows and your program is 32-bits. When you open a file in `c:\Windows\System32`, it will be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. So you are not copying `c:\windows\system32\calc.exe`, but `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe` instead. I asume that calc.exe has a filesize of 798720.

See also [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Excellent answer @Wimmel!  This seems to be the case.  Sorry I don't have the points to vote you up.